# Ternary logic for created a dijit in dojo

Tags: javascript

This is fairly simple to do in a if/else but, I am trying to get into ternary logic and how it works. This is my first attempt at it.

```
 if(condtion == true){
                        var showProtected = new dijit.form.CheckBox({                                                               
                            checked: true
                        })else{
                            showProtected = new dijit.form.CheckBox({
                            checked: false
                            });     
                        });
                         showProtected.placeAt("showProtected", "first");   
}
```

I tired but does not work:

```
showProtected = (condition == true) ? new dijit.form.CheckBox({                                                             
                            checked: true
                        }) : new dijit.form.CheckBox({
                            checked: false
                        });     
                         showProtected.placeAt("showProtected", "first");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make it even simpler and just say:

```
var showProtected = new dijit.form.CheckBox({
  checked: (condition == true)
});
```

Comment: I went with this to no avail.       if (condition.Protected == true) {
       var showProtected = new dijit.form.CheckBox({
         checked: (condition == true)
       });
      }

Comment: I'm confused, do you want to say: `var showProtected = new dijit.form.CheckBox({ checked: (condition == true) });`

Comment: I want to create a dijit checkbox regardless but only want it checked if condition == true. In my mind I thought I could assign the dijit to a variable and then if(condition == false){variable.checked=false;} but, I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(condition){                     
                        var pro = new dijit.form.CheckBox({
                            id: "true",                                 
                            title: "Checked",
                            checked: true
                        });                         

                    }else{
                        var pro = new dijit.form.CheckBox({
                            id: "false",                                
                            title: "Unchecked",
                            checked: false
                        });             
                    }
                    pro.placeAt("showCheckbox", "first");
```

Comment: Now if there is a ternary way of doing this I would still love to see it as that was the whole purpose of this exercise :)

Comment: Why do you want to use a ternary operator, though? The `if` statement is probably the cleanest way to do it, unless the condition is small in which case I would code it up as per my answer (that way you do not repeat yourself with the code to declare `pro`). The only real time you want to use a ternary operator is when it is convenient to write the code as an expression, such as `var pro = (condition) ? x : y;`.